# Spring property placeholder not working inside an import directive

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring configuration with a property placeholder directive attribute that is not being recognised. I have verified that the actual property can be resolved by creating a simple class that outputs the property:

```xml
<bean id="propTest" class="com.johnsands.unite.PropertyLogger">
  <constructor-arg value="security.configuration"/>
  <constructor-arg value="${security.configuration}"/>
</bean>
```

This simple bean outputs the given parameters, which it does just fine. But when I try to use that same property in an import, as in the following:

```xml
<import resource="${security.configuration}"/>
```

I get the following error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'security.configuration' in string value "${security.configuration}"

This does not make sense as I have verified the property can be resolved. It also appears that the directive should be supported as spring is trying to resolve the placeholder but is not able to.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1358

Comment: Thanks, that sucks. Know if there's a way to get a placeholder to resolve to an empty string if it's not set? I do not want tone using system properties.

Comment: Overwrite `convertProperty` and return something sensitive. Feels like a hack though...